# TextBlock binding not working

Tags: wpf, binding, textblock

I have a `TextBlock` that bind to property in my model. My model sitting in my view model that bind with the window.

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding MyModel.TextVar,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></TextBlock>
```

TextVar is a string property that call function of Notify...

So, I do not understand why it does not work. (There is no binding error in the OutPut).

**EDIT:**

```
    string _textVar;
    public string TextVar
    {
        get
        {
            return _textVar;
        }
        set
        {
            _textVar= value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("TextVar");
        }
    }


    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)-- HERE THE PROPBLEM, IT ARRIVE NULL
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
```

Comment: what does your view model code look like? How have you bound your UI? Have you tried debugging: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsldesigner/archive/2010/06/30/debugging-data-bindings-in-a-wpf-or-silverlight-application.aspx

Comment: Have you set the DataContext?

Comment: @ColineE look on my edit

Comment: @Kai I set, I hava other binding that work

Comment: Put {Binding = XAMLSucks} and it will build. This is because XAML sucks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Binding TextBlock with Mode=TwoWay makes no sense because its a TextBlock and not a TextBox.

but nevertheless your binding work if the DataContext of your textblock has a Property "MyModel" and this "MyModel" - object has a Property "TextVar".

if you wanna look up your datacontext and binding at runtime use [Snoop](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/)

EDIT: that what you need if you do your binding like you did

```
public class MyViewmodel
{
  public MyOtherClass MyModel {get;set;}
}

public class MyOtherClass
{
   public string TextVar {get;set;}
}
```

windows.xaml.cs ctor:

```
 this.data = new MyViewmodel(); 
 this.DataContext = this.data;
```

Comment: nope this would work, i did an example :) pls check your binding and datacontext at runtime with Snoop

Comment: the PropertyChanged arrive allways null!

Comment: that is strange, my example works. can you change your binding to Mode=OneWay and without UpdateSourceTrigger - you did not need this anyway

Comment: I passed the variable to the ViewModel and it worked .. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Seems that everything is perfect, now just add this line under the constructor of your class.

```
        this.DataContext = this;
```

The problem arries when you have declared another DataContext in some parent window. I was suffering from same problem and this solution worked for me.

**A Quick Review of Binding a TextBox in WPF**

**Step 1: Declare a property in class of window**

first of all, you should declare a property in class of you window, i.e in .xml.cs file of your new window.

```
string _someVariable;
public string NameOfProperty
{
    get
    {
        return _someVariable;
    }
    set
    {
        _someVariable= value;
    }
}
```

**Step 2: Bind the property to TextBox**

Now bind your TextBox to your newly created property using the following syntax.

```
{Binding Path=NameOfProperty}
```

The Path notes the property that you want to bind to, however, since Path is the default property of a binding, you may leave it out if you want to, like this:

```
{Binding NameOfProperty}
```

**Step 3: Declare the DataContext of your Window**
Your solution should work until now, but in case you are using some pattern you should define the DataContext of your window.